# Creating a Zip file programmatically C++

Tags: c++, zip

I am trying to find a lib that will allow me to produce a zip file. I have a list of files that I want to place into the archive. The first suggestion I had was to use boost with zlib, however that turned out to be a dead end. I also looked at zziplib, however its a read only lib.

If anyone has any experience with doing this, and had used a lib successfully before I would love to hear about it.

This is for a C++ project in MSVC9, and the lib must be free to use commercially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Zip Utils](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-Clean-Elegant-Simple-Cplusplus-Win).

> WARNING: This code has known bugs. It doesn't deal with non-ASCII filenames correctly. It doesn't deal with passwords correctly.

Comment: My difficulty with using zLib was that I was having a very hard time finding tutorials or usage examples to help me use it. Not only was Zip Utils simple to use, and documented, but dropped into my project and worked instantly. Also it is only two files that came "from restructuring the internals of zlib and info-zip source code" which means its simple with the reliability of zLib. Perfect.

Comment: I have never used it myself but it seemed simple to use and like you said, it is derived from zlib like you wanted.

Answer (score 8):

Use zlib without boost. Zlib is pretty much the easiest way to deal with ZIP files in tight memory and time, but it is a C library and most attempts to C++ify it have fallen down miserably and just made more trouble than simply biting the bullet and working with pointers and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Why was zlib a "dead end"? It's probably what you should be using. Maybe someone here can help you figure out how to get it to work.